# Insert or update data in aerospike

Tags: database, aerospike

I want to insert some record in Aerospike, if the record already exists then I only want to update it.
Currently I am using this query(to insert) -

> client.put(wPolicy, key,bin1,bin2)

Can someone please inform me how to update or insert depending on whether the record is duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **default write policy**, which does the following:

(1) If the specified bins do not yet exist, they will be inserted; and

(2) If the specified bins exist and have values, those values will be replaced.

To use the default write policy, if you're using the Java client, just pass in `null` to the `writePolicy` parameter. I suspect other clients will be similar.

If there are more sub-parts to your question, you can add details to your question and I'll revisit later.

Answer (score 2):

As [Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1146596/aaron) mentioned, the default [write policy](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#write-policies) for existence is [`AS_POLICY_EXISTS_IGNORE`](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/c/db/d65/group__client__policies.html#ga50b94613bcf416c9c2691c9831b89238), which means "Write the record, regardless of existence. (i.e. create or update.)". Therefore, you don't have to set the existence policy explicitly, as it already does what you expect.

You can choose to have a more SQL-like behavior, with `AS_POLICY_EXISTS_CREATE` (with the write failing if the record already exists), `AS_POLICY_EXISTS_UPDATE` (with the write failing if the record doesn't already exists), and `AS_POLICY_EXISTS_REPLACE` (with the write failing if the record doesn't exist, AND what you write always replacing the previous version completely) and `AS_POLICY_EXISTS_CREATE-OR-REPLACE` (which either creates a new record if none exists, or completely overwrites the record if it does).

In the [Python client](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python) you would set one of these alternative existence write policies on the [`aerospike.Client.put()`](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike.Client.put):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import aerospike
from aerospike.exception import RecordError

config = {
    'hosts': [ ('127.0.0.1', 3000) ],
    'timeout': 1500
}
client = aerospike.client(config).connect()
try:
    key = ('test', 'users', 1)
    bins = {
        'username': 'ninjastar',
        'age': 47,
        'hp': 1234
    }
    client.put(key, bins,
             policy={'exists': aerospike.POLICY_EXISTS_CREATE},
             meta={'ttl': 3600})
except RecordError as e:
    print("The user record already exists: {0} [{1}]".format(e.msg, e.code))
    sys.exit(1)
finally:
    client.close()
```

The possible values for *exists* are [`aerospike.POLICY_EXISTS_*`](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/aerospike.html#policies).